# How to run Meld (1.5) with python 2.4.3

Tags: python, redhat-enterprise-linux, meld

I would like to run Meld (a diff tool written in python) but it quits with the following error :

```
Meld requires Python 2.5 or higher.
```

Facing restrictive corporate guidelines i have to stick to the already installed Python 2.4.3
Is there a way to make Meld run despite that?

My system is RHEL 5.5

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be quite difficult to backport Meld to Python 2.4. [Here are the Python 2.5 features](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/whatsnew25.html), and some of them look like a real pain to get rid of.

Comment: Arrr! Its too bad. I had a slim hope because on the [meld homepage](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) the requirements say "2.4 or higher". But on the other hand the site still advertises the 1.3 release with 1.5 out for two month already.

Comment: The 1.3 works as expected though. Could be worse :). Thank you, Daniel Beck

Comment: Even the 1.4 works. I was simply discouraged by the uncooperative ops.

Comment: RHEL is a server platform. meld is a GUI diff/merge client. Do you run RHEL on your workstation? Also, as alternative you could try using diffuse (http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/), it claims to work with python 2.4

Comment: Thank you, vtest. Yeah, its a local RHEL install, i guess its a result of a one-size-fits-all purchase policy at the company i work at ATM (that would also explain the lousy monitors we all get). Unfortunately diffuse only comes as an rpm and i am no SU. Sure they've got the source download as well but since i've got Meld 1.4 working now and no real python experience i'll leave it at that for now